# Symfony2 form - Customize birthday type

Tags: forms, symfony

How can I customize birthday type in Symfony2? There is no

```
{% block birthday_widget %}
```

in [form_div_layout](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)

Comment: @NitishKumar in the `select`box. So the example a bove should be `<select id="dateOfBirth_month" required="required" name="[dateOfBirth][month]" class="valid span2">`

Comment: @NitishKumar if you look at the above code, I added **span2** in the class

Answer (score 0):

The birthday form type gets rendered with the block choice_widget.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_expanded') }}
    {% else %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_collapsed') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

In the end, the block doing the output is named choice_widget_collapsed. Just make your changes in there.

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required and empty_value is none and not empty_value_in_choices %}
        {% set required = false %}
    {% endif %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
    </select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```